# How can I filtered array of object with array by item inside it ? javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, iteration

I want to filter this array of object by one favoriteCities for example by Paris but it's not working, I wouls like to get an array with the object that contain "Paris" in the favoriteCities, please hep I tried several options

```
       const favCity= [{
                    name: "shaun",
                    favoriteCities: ["Paris", "London"]
                  },
                  {
                    name: "valerie",
                    favoriteCities: ["Paris", "NewYork"]
                  },
                  {
                    name: "peter",
                    favoriteCities: ["London", "Berlin"]
                  }
                ]
            
            const res = favCity.filter((ele,i)=>{

 return {
   name: ele.name,
   favoriteCities: ele.favoriteCities.filter(element=>
         element === "Paris" ? ele.favoriteCities : [])
        }
});


console.log(res)
```

Comment: `ele.favoriteCities.includes("Paris")`?

Comment: You haven't supplied code that makes sense. Is that a function `return`ing an Object? `});` suggests not. `ele.favoriteCities`? Where's that? `console.log(res)`? `res` is not defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let favCity= [{
                    name: "shaun",
                    favoriteCities: ["Paris", "London"]
                  },
                  {
                    name: "valerie",
                    favoriteCities: ["Paris", "NewYork"]
                  },
                  {
                    name: "peter",
                    favoriteCities: ["London", "Berlin"]
                  }
                ]
            
favCity = favCity.filter(element => element.favoriteCities.includes("Paris"))

console.log(favCity)
```